# Integrate Twitter fabric Digits phonegap/Cordova

Tags: android, ios, cordova, phonegap-plugins

I have done some googling and could not find any plugins for integrating **twitter digits** with **Phonegap/Cordova** applications. I am looking for iOS and Android.

Can anyone suggest any blogs or guidelines for the same? Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You will have to create a plugin, as digits only offers an iOS and android native SDK

Comment: I've been looking into this and I don't see possible to create a generic cordova plugin for digits as twitter SDK integration requires to use their Fabrik app that register your app on the Fabrik.io site

Comment: Hi, not sure if you guys are still looking for a way to do this but I've created a solution https://github.com/yangli1990/digits-cordova

Comment: @YangLi, but you use the digits for web, and digits for web only support login, you can't use it to register new users

Comment: Why can't log in the first time be the same as registering an account?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

They have just launched digits for web, take a look https://dev.twitter.com/twitter-kit/web/digits

If you still want to use the native SDKs, as I told you on a comment it's impossible to create a generic cordova plugin to just install it via the cordova CLI, at least for iOS you will have to open xcode and follow the fabric app instructions

Comment: Yeah. I saw that. But it is not supporting signup, only login

Comment: Then you will have to wait, I think they are working on it. Or you can try to integrate the SDK using the fabric app, and create a simple plugin for you that calls the signup code

Comment: why the downvotes? I contacted to digits team and confirmed they are working on the web sign up

Comment: @jcesarmobile Tx for solution. Just to confirm - I can include these files in my phonegap build - and use in them in app. Isnt the sdk domain specific (like facebook www sdk) and thus can only be used on the hosted website rather than app?

Comment: It's an online script, you should have to add the url to your whitelist plugin and CSP tag if you have one. I think you can use it, but the truth is I didn't try